# How to select elements in scrapy loop?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to loop through elements in a website to create items from them. However, the loop returns the entire list of responses for every item, instead of individual items.

Website code:

```py
<div id="resultsList">

<div class="result">
<div ...>
<p><b><a href="...">
<spctc>CONTENT I</spctc>
</a></b></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="result">
<div ...>
<p><b><a href="...">
<spctc>CONTENT II</spctc>
</a></b></p>
</div>
</div>

...

</div>
```

My spider code (I have to login first, so the spider goes through a few functions before passing the logged in website on to the scrape function instead and not the parse function):

```py
def scrape(self, response):      
    for article in response.xpath('//div[@class="result"]'):
        item = Article() # Creating a new Article object
        item['title'] = article.xpath('//spctc/text()').extract()
        print(item)

        yield item
```

Using this code, every item looks the same:

```py
{'title': ['CONTENT I',
           'CONTENT II', ...]}
```

I would like to have the first item as

```py
{'title': ['CONTENT I']}
```

, the second item as

```py
{'title': ['CONTENT II']}
```

, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try iterating over the articles list instead...
article.xpath('//spctc/text()')

Comment: Thanks, this works for getting the titles, but I need other content from each section during the loop.

Comment: possible create a new loop to go over the output from the function and make another dictionary to store it?

Answer (score 0):

```py
item['title'] = article.xpath('.//spctc/text()').extract()
```

did the trick